# Create testdata with List<string>, Autofixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

Trying to get this simple test to work:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<string> Comments { get; set; }

}
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.Customize<string>(c => c.FromSeed(s => s)); //Just return propertyname, no GUID appended
        var test = fixture.Create<MyClass>();

    }
}
```

but I keep getting the error

> The decorated `ISpecimenBuilder` could not create a specimen based on the request: System.String. This can happen if the request represents an interface or abstract class; if this is the case, register an `ISpecimenBuilder` that can create specimens based on the request. If this happens in a strongly typed `Build<T>` expression, try supplying a factory using one of the `IFactoryComposer<T>` methods.`

If I remove the `Customize` line, is seems to work...

Not quite sure what I need to do to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `string` instances without appending a `GUID` by customizing the `Fixture` instance as shown below:

```
public void GuidsAreNotAppendedOnStringValues()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var expected = string.Empty;
    fixture.Customizations.Add(
        new StringGenerator(() => expected));

    var actual = fixture.Create<MyClass>();

    Assert.Equal(expected, actual.Comments.Aggregate((x, y) => x + y));
}
```

That way also the `Text` property is *Text*, instead of *Texte85e2f6f-c1a3-47c7-baf2-4756c498f523*.

Comment: But then it seems like all the entries in my comment list are empty... would like them to be filled with something too...

Answer (score 0):

Ended up, adding my own ISpecimenBuilder

```
public class TextBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var pi = request as PropertyInfo;
        if (pi == null)
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            return pi.Name;
        if (pi.PropertyType == typeof(IList<string>) || pi.PropertyType == typeof(List<string>))
        {
            var tmps = (List<string>)context.Resolve(typeof(List<string>));
            for (var n = 0; n != tmps.Count; ++n)
                tmps[n] = pi.Name + n.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return tmps;
        }
        return new NoSpecimen(request);
    }
}
```